# How to write lists of data to a .csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to write lists of information onto a .csv file in python. So far, I've only been able to get the header to print. I want to grab 2 columns from an existing .csv file to write into the new .csv file with my data. so far, I have

```
def get_id_size():
    read_file = pandas.read_csv('poem_info.csv')
    poemid = (read_file[['poemname']])
    poemsize = (read_file[['poemsize']])
    return (poemid, poemsize) #this is the columns i want in my new.csv file

    with open('poem_data.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        # write header
        outfile.write('poemid,poemsize,cli,ari\n')
```

my new data is in

```
        cli = calculate_cli
        ari = calculate_ari
```

So my question would be: How can I assign poemid, poemsize, cli, and ari to a csv file? I'm very new to python and I can't figure out the syntax to do so

Comment: Do you actually need `pandas`? Doesn't seem like you're using it for much of anything that the built-in `csv` module (particularly on Py3, where it's Unicode friendly) couldn't handle.

Comment: I don't particularly need it, but I thought it would be faster if I read into the existing csv file using pandas

Comment: Are `calculate_cli()` and `calculate_ari()` using the value from `poemid` and `poemsize`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas is not required but it will simplify your life. You could do the following (removing the function `get_id_size()` altogether):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('poem_info.csv')

# Change the column name of poemname
df.rename(columns={'poemname':'poemid'}, inplace=True)

# Add the new columns
df['cli'] = calculate_cli()
df['ari'] = calculate_ari()

# Export
df.to_csv('poem_data.csv',header=True,index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not a `pandas` guru, but you don't really need it here:

```
import csv

with open('poem.csv', newline='') as inf,
     open('poem_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as outf:
    csvout = csv.writer(outf)
    csvout.writerow(['poemid', 'poemsize', 'cli', 'ari'])
    for (poemid, size, *_), c, a in zip(csv.reader(inf), cli, ari):
        csvout.writerow([poemid, size, c, a])
```

That reads from the input file (ignoring all fields past the first two; if the fields are actually index 1 and 3, you could use `for (_, poemid, _, size, *_), c, a in zip(...):` instead), pairs them up with your computed values, then writes them out. I'm sure there is a nicer way in `pandas`, but this doesn't require third party modules at all, so it may be preferable in some cases.

To split this up into functions, you'd need to either open the file outside the function or listify the results (so the `with` block doesn't cut off access to the file before you're done. For example:

```
def get_id_size():
    with open('poem.csv', newline='') as inf:
        return [(poemid, size) for poemid, size, *_ in csv.reader(inf)]

cli = calculate_cli()
ari = calculate_ari()

with open('poem_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    csvout = csv.writer(outfile)
    # write header
    csvout.writerow(['poemid', 'poemsize', 'cli', 'ari'])
    for (poemid, size), c, a in zip(get_id_size(), cli, ari):
        csvout.writerow([poemid, size, c, a])
```

Note: This is Py3 code; changes would be needed for the Py2 `csv` module.

Comment: Thanks! I'm running in Py3, but when I implemented your code, I get an     "csvout.writerow(['poemid', 'poemsize', 'cli', 'ari'])
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable" error

Comment: @emptybladder: Yeah, typo. Forgot to pass the mode when opening for write. Already fixed (just added `'w'` as second argument to `open` for `outf`. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: (at least on Windows) you should open `csv.writer` files as binary. `open('poem_data.csv', 'wb', newline='')` EDIT: oh hmm, maybe that's just in py2

Comment: @AdamSmith: That's only for Python 2. On Python 3, you want text mode (`csv` writes `str`, not `bytes`); the `newline=''` is what prevents line ending translation (so `csv` writes newlines appropriate to the dialect regardless of Windows vs. Linux vs. old Mac weirdness). See [the modern docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), specifically [the final footnote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3).

Comment: @ShadowRanger aye, just old crufts of long-deprecated knowledge from the days of yore cropping up in my head. Thanks for the clarification!